Javascript Object Array, Iterate over only one object
I have a javascript array object. I want to find the result of a single array.  The following code does what I want but always iterates over the whole array.  How can I achieve the same on just one array?


b = [];
b[0] = {};
b[0].pts = [1,4,8,12,1];
b[0].result = 0;

b[1] = {};
b[1].pts = [2,1,3,2,10,12];
b[1].result = 0;

b[2] = {};
b[2].pts = [5,1,9];
b[2].result = 0;

/* Iterates over entire object */
b.forEach(
    e=>e.pts.forEach((c,i)=>{
        if(i && c<=4){
            e.result += c
        };
        if(e.pts[0]<=3 && i==0){
            e.result+=e.pts[0];
        };
    })
);

console.log(">> "+b[0].result+"<br/>");
console.log(">> "+b[1].result+"<br/>");
console.log(">> "+b[2].result+"<br/>");

/* Iterate over a single object */



Thanks.

Can you explain more, what do you mean by always iterate over the whole array?
And what is the expected scenario like, what do you want it to do?

If you want to find values that are not greater than 4, then, yes, you have to look at every element in that array. How else will you know you haven't missed such a case?

Disappointing that you take the trouble to ask a question but then don't react to comments, or the answer that was posted by Noah.

I don't entirely understand what you mean to say. The code you provided indeed calculates the result for every object in the array, but it does not 'always run over the whole array', it does this exactly once. Are you meaning to say that you want to calculate the result only when you fetch the value?
In that case, you can use a function to calculate the result like so:
const getResult = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

console.log(getResult(b[0].pts));

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.
